# Java: Extract all links with a certain word in them with JSoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

Might be an unclear question so here's the code and explanation:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(exampleHtmlData);

    Elements certainLinks = doc.select("a[href=google.com/example/]");
```

The String exampleHtmlData contains a parsed HTML source from a certain site. This site has a lot of links which direct the user to google. A few examples would be:

```
http://google.com/example/hello 
http://google.com/example/certaindir/anotherdir/something
http://google.com/anotherexample
```

I want to extract all the links that contain google.com/example/ in the link with the doc.select function. How do I do this with JSoup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can refer the [SelectorSyntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(exampleHtmlData);
Elements certainLinks = doc.select("a[href*=google.com/example/]");
```